# "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400" while recording application using JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to record a web application using Jmeter. I am able to record the launch of home page but facing error while logging in. I can see this error in the Network tab of chrome Dev Tools.

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

```
main.js?v=1579205232764:2 WebSocket connection to 'wss://<server-ip>/study-search?authorization=<token-value>' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [current JMeter version 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html)  JMeter cannot either capture or properly proxy the [WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) traffic so I would recommend splitting the recording in 2 parts:

1. Before the login (including the login)
2. After the login (to wit: login without proxy, then turn on proxy, then continue recording)

In any case all the WebSocket calls needs to be captured separately using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and then properly simulated using [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide/) plugin

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, the WebSocket Samplers look promising. Will try out that option first.